# What should be the standard success, failure and error JSON response formats for REST APIs?

Tags: json, rest

What should be the standard format for returning success JSON, failure JSON and error JSON? I visited many so called RESTful APIs but almost all have their own way to return success, failure and error JSON? Is there any recommended JSON format that should be followed/referenced?

Thanks

Comment: What are failure and error conditions in your system?

Comment: Validation fails are failures. All 5xx are errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Standard JSON API response format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806386/standard-json-api-response-format)

Answer (score 0):

Good question. REST does set some conventions, but unlike for GET or PUT HTML where there is at least a convention for the tag names to be sent, there is little about the vocabulary to be used for JSON... I believe any truly useful long-term usage will need to develop formal vocabularies beyond basic transaction behaviors, whether HTML, XMPP, or a dialect of JSON (e.g., in XMPP, unlike say WebSockets alone, you can develop clients which know how to handle subscription and publishing for any Pubsub server).

Comment: What "tag names" are sent for `GET` or `PUT` "HTML" Do you mean HTTP status codes?

Comment: No, I just mean `<html>`, `<body>`,  etc., within the message content There is some fixed vocabulary sent along.

Answer (score 0):

To signal Success, errors or any other status you should use standard http status codes. 
You can also in case of an error return a json containing something like code, severity and message.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the [HTTP Status Codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html) as per its description. It will be good to have all your REST failure/error responses to have some common fields like `errorCode` and `errorMessage` that describes the status you are sending back.

```
{
    "apiStatus":{        
        "errorCode":"validation.error.invalidId",
        "errorMessage":"The Id entered is not valid"
    }
    "yourContentIfany": ....
}
```